# How to develop a Pluggable/Installable Module Based Application in ASP.net/ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, plugins, module

I am desiging the architecture of an application which will have many sub applications in it. Those sub-applications will be a developed by us but on a later stage.

I want to create those sub-applications as installable plugin / module which might have multiple pages (.aspx pages) which should be able to interact with the Main Core Application and consume its shared data also.

I strictly need The Plugins/Modules to be installable by **manipulating the configuration** or **adding a folder of files** or **a DLL**.

My Application will be an ASP.net web application. If ASP.net MVC solves the purpose then I can also look up for that also.

My Application will make use of URLs to Identify the Module to be loaded. Following are some Examples of some URLs which I wish to have my application.

e.g.

http://www.myCoreApp.com/Module1/

http://www.myCoreApp.com/crm/

www.myCoreApp.com will host my Core Application in which my Modules will be installed.

Module1, crm, accounting and xyz are installed modules on My Core App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should take look at MEF ([Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/)). It makes no difference if your app is ASP.NET web forms or MVC, or even if is Winforms

Comment: Thanks Antonio for the reply. I looked into the MEF documentation on Code project but wasn't able to implement it. can you guide me through a tutorial or some sample code in which I can look upon..?

Comment: look at http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.com/2010/04/very-basic-mef-sample-using-importmany.html and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brada/archive/2009/07/20/simple-example-using-managed-extensibility-framework-in-silverlight.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I would go for MVC.

One could auto-discover the modules --- probably by convention and by checking implementation of a certain initialization type like IModule.

Then you could register your Controllers within a DI container (like Windsor) so all the 'shared' components will be injected by the container.

HTH